# regex doesnt match the line starts with character e

Tags: regex, node.js, ascii

I have such a regex:

```
/^[^(\-.+\n|content|\n\-.+\-{2})](.+)/igm
```

This is a sample input:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryKanSEkvcMamqayJY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fl"; filename="emty"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

this is trial

------WebKitFormBoundaryKanSEkvcMamqayJY--
```

I want to capture every line except those below:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryKanSEkvcMamqayJY
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fl"; filename="emty"
    Content-Type: application/octet-stream  
------WebKitFormBoundaryKanSEkvcMamqayJY--
```

This regex works well unless the line starts with following characters:

```
e,t,o,+,|,c,n,.
```

I guess this is something about character ASCII codes range and no idea how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid there is a bigger issue with your regex. In short, `[^(\-.+\n|content|\n\-.+\-{2})]` matches just 1 character as it is a character class.

Assuming the lines that you want to ignore start with more than 3 `-`s and `Content-`, you can use the following regex:

```
/^(?!-{3,}|content-).+$/igm
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sC2lD6/2)

And just in case there can be leading whitespace, I'd use a safer version:

```
/^(?!\s*(?:-{3,}|content-)).+$/igm
```

And finally, if you need to match empty lines, replace `.+` with `.*`.

Comment: i especially didnt add g fag because data comes from request in small peaces and the problem javascript behaves strange when u use g flag

Comment: `g` just makes a global search. It should behave well once your regex is matching what you need.

Comment: in javascript it matches last index  and gives error anyway my data streams line by line so no problem with this

Comment: I see. Also, in the regex, the multiline mode `m` also ensures line-by-line behavior. So, it must be safe enough.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
/^(?!\s*(-|Content)).*/
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/gOp9esUPQs)

Comment: I am not sure it is safe, have a look at [this demo](http://rubular.com/r/7JZKErbweC)